# didSelect execution not waiting for didDeSelect animation to end

Tags: ios, swift, animation, mapkit

I have a map with multiple map pins. Each pin, when clicked, will display a view with information specific to the pin that was selected. So lets say location info about the pin.

Imagine the following use case:

1- When a pin is selected, animate the display of a view with information about the selected pin.

2- When a different pin is selected, animate the hiding of the view that is selected in step 1.

3- Once the animation from step 2 is finished, animate the display of a view with specific information about the newly selected pin.

I have implemented the following mapKit functions

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

            // Animate views

        })

}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView){
     // did select code

     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

          // Animate views

     })
}
```

Once I try to perform the action for step 2, the didDeselct function is executed. Then after this, the logic in the didSelect function is executed. This works but there is one problem. The execution of the animation in the didDeselect does not finish before the didSelect function is executed.

How can I block the execution of didSelect until the animation in the didDeselct is complete.

Keep in mind I still need the didSelect function so I cannot place the logic of this function, inside the animate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to write a function to display and hide the related `view`. This function will be required to take care of both of the processes. Also you can create a `Bool` variable to know if any animation is ongoing. If it is, then make wait for it be done and trigger the function again when it is done. You can use `get`, `set` blocks of a variable or `Observer Pattern`. I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was thinking but I thought there was some way of doing this that was built into the framework. I will try this out.

Comment: Maybe there is a way that is built into the framework, but I am not a person who has that much experience in swift. Try this if it works, no problem; if not, please inform me.

Comment: Thanks, Worked nicely